# How to display in a Primary window from a secondary thread for a video player

Tags: c#, c++, user-interface, directx

I am creating a video player application with a UI in C# and the video decoding and display (DirectX) in C++.

The C++ code is compiled as a DLL and interfaced with the C# UI.

To maintain the correct display frame rate I need to create a secondary thread either in C++ DLL or C# which can do accurate timing and call the display function at right intervals.

However, creating a secondary thread which posts display to the window created by the primary thread (from C# GUI) creates access violation and results in a crash.

However, if I use a timer object in C# to display, the player works but I am unable to maintain the right frame rate due to it's coarse granularity.

What would be a good solution to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the crashes you experience are caused by the fact that you can't access Windows Forms controls from outside the main thread.

Consider using [Control.Invoke()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) to invoke the execution you need on the main thread.

Bear in mind though that `Control.Invoke()` uses Windows' message queue to pass the request through, so expect some inaccuracies.

Comment: However, Control.Invoke posts the call back to the message queue.  So your timing will not be 100% exact -- that is, the call will not be executed at that time, but maybe a few ms behind depending whether there are higher-priority messages ahead in the message queue.  This may cause problems with lip sync.

Comment: Is there any reason why you need to present each frame by yourself and not letting DirectX to do it for you?

Comment: DirectX is being used to process and draw, but decoder is our own. Any suggestions on how to maintain lip sync?